# How to mantain active a nav tab using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this js to put active a nav tab in my web page:

```
  $('a[href="' + this.location.pathname + '"]').parents('li,ul').addClass('active');
```

It works in the same level(secured/buyer_user/inbox/get/new_purchase)of the view, but if I change a location like secured/buyer_user/inbox/get/new_purchase the nav tab get inactive.

I have the following page structure:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="nav" name="nav"> 
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav hover">
           <li>...<li>
        <ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: More information about your webpage please

Comment: It's only about URLs, it doesn't need more information.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  var loc = window.location.pathname;

   $('#nav').find('a').each(function() {
     $(this).toggleClass('active', $(this).attr('href') == loc);
  });
```

Comment: It's doesn't work I have the following structure <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="nav" name="nav">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav hover">

Comment: can you provide full code to the `<li>` or `<a>` tag.

Comment: check that >>in your <li> a tag's `href` is a full absolute path??